# Why the log is not working in my WSO2 custom message processor implementation?

Tags: java, wso2, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I am trying to do some first preliminar experiment building a **custom message processor**. I basically created a project in which I define a class that extends the WSO2 **SamplingProcessor** abstract class. This is a very minimalistic experiment so at this time I am only overriding some methods putting some log inside.

It seems that my application works and that this custom message processor is used bit I can't read the inserted log into my **wso2carbon.log** log file.

I have do in this way:

1) I created a new Maven project and I use this **pom.xml** file that should fit the requirement to build a custom message processor:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.toolkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Sampling Processor Header Rate Limitation</name>
    <description>Custom Sampling Mesageprocessor using response header to implement the rate limitation</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>com.mycompany.toolkit.*</Export-Package>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>*</DynamicImport-Package>
                        <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        <Scm-Root>${project.scm.connection}</Scm-Root>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7-wso2v3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <CApp.type>lib/synapse/mediator</CApp.type>
    </properties>
</project>
```

2) Then I created this **SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation** that is my custom message processor implementation and that extends the **SamplingProcessor** WSO2 message processor class:

```
package com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.synapse.SynapseException;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.ScheduledMessageProcessor;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor;
import org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessorView;

public class SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation extends SamplingProcessor {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ScheduledMessageProcessor.class.getName());
    private SamplingProcessorView view;

    @Override
    public void init(SynapseEnvironment se) {
        super.init(se);

        logger.info("init() START");
        System.out.println("init() START");

        try {
            view = new SamplingProcessorView(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SynapseException(e);
        }

        // register MBean
        org.apache.synapse.commons.jmx.MBeanRegistrar.getInstance().registerMBean(view,
                "Message Sampling Processor view", getName());

        logger.info("init() END");
        System.out.println("init() END");
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameters(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        logger.info("setParameters() START");
        System.out.println("setParameters() START");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setParameters(parameters);

        logger.info("setParameters() END");
        System.out.println("setParameters() END");
    }
}
```

As you can see I am overriding some methods like **init()** (because I think that it is performed once, but when?) and **setParameters()** (for the same reason).

As you can see I tried to put the log using the **Log logger** instance but also using a simple **System.out.println()**.

I build it generating the jar file and I uploaded this jar inside **WSO2 EI** administration panel: **ESB Artifacts --> Add**.

Then I am trying to use this custom message processor in my ESB application, configuring this message processor in this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!---<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor" messageStore="transferFromMessageStore" name="transferFromMessageProcessor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">-->
<messageProcessor class="com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor.SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation" messageStore="transferFromMessageStore" name="transferFromMessageProcessor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="sequence">transferProcessorSequence</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="concurrency">1</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

As you can see I replaced the standard **org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.sampler.SamplingProcessor** message processor (previously used by this ESB application) with my custom message processor (**com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor.SamplingProcessorHeaderRateLimitation**).

My application seems to work fine (so I think that it is using this custom message processor, I hope it) but the log inserted into the **init()** and **setParameters()** methods are not printed into my log file (**wso2carbon.log**).

Why? What caould be the problem? What am I missing?

I check the log after that I call my WSO2 ESB API so I can see only what happens after that the API is called (I am doing a unix tail on the log).

Could be that these 2 overrided methods are executed only at the startup of the Carbon server or when the ESB application is deployed?

Eventually what message processor method can I override to test the log? (I mean a method that is called each time that my custom message processor execute its related sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think that it is performed once, but when?** - During init, I think this happen when you edit some MessageProcessor and press save button, you will notice something like

```
[2017-07-20 13:45:41,477] [] INFO - ScheduledMessageProcessor Started message processor. [meneriade]
```

About logging

```
logger.info("init() START");
```

Have you checked log4j.properties? You do have custom package name

```
package com.mycompany.toolkit.messageprocessor;
```